# Run 'dd' command from Android APK as root - is it possible?

Tags: java, android

I'm struggling to find a definitive answer on the inter-who, so I'll ask here.

Is it possible to execute low level commands (such as DD) from an Android APK when the device is rooted?

Comment: Why not just try it out yourself?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, execute it with `su -c "command"`.